# C#: How to prevent a laptop from going into Stand-By

Tags: c#, power-management

How can I do this in a C# program? I'm pretty sure it should be possible, since various media programs for example do this so the computer doesn't go into stand-by while watching a movie, etc.

So, if I for example create a plain and basic WinForm application, what do I need to do to prevent a laptop from going into Stand-By as long as this application is running?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you'll have to P/Invoke.  But don't be scared... it's pretty easy.

[SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208.aspx) is your friend. [It's available](https://github.com/AArnott/pinvoke/commit/f382340dc2243622aee3dd82924e355494dd6211#diff-332753c43f250ed731f39b109faaafb4R1827) in the [PInvoke project](https://github.com/AArnott/pinvoke/), also available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pinvoke.kernel32).

Comment: Looks perfect! Can't test it until tonight or tomorrow though, but it looks right :)

Comment: Do I have to set the state back when my application exits? Or, since it is a per thread/application thing, will it go back to normal automatically?

Comment: Unless the documentation states you need to go back manually, I'd say that you probably don't have to set it back if you mean for it to last the life of your app.

Comment: From the documentation you linked: 'Also note that this setting is per thread/application not global'.

Comment: Dan G said in his answer that the proposed solution doesn't work in Windows 10.

Comment: Hello does this solution prevent computer to sleeping when your application is running?