# Preveting computer from going to sleep with program C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sleep

I'm working on a WinForm project and I'm almost done, but I need this one last thing.
My program needs to be running at all time when using it so I need some way to prevent the computer from going to sleep. I need this functionality basically so you can let the program run when you're not using the computer to save time.

If you've ever used a mac you probably know what Caffeine for mac is. This is an app that prevents the mac from going to sleep. I need something like this, but it needs to be integrated to the app.

Does anyone know how I could do this? :)

Thanks!

Comment: I hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302185/how-to-prevent-windows-from-entering-idle-state a head start.

Comment: For what version of windows is your app??