# Is there a way in Qt to prohibit the computer from going to sleep?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I am writing a Qt application that does some heavy computations, but on a Mac (potentially also on Windows but I currently have no way of checking this), the execution ceases as soon as the computer goes into sleeping mode.

I would like a way to continue the execution even when the screen goes to screensaver or on blank. Obviously you can ask the user to change his/her energy settings, but that's far from an ideal solution. Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Dunno if Qt has an API to do it, but for Mac this should work:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8461182/131930

Comment: It's unclear to me whether with "sleep" you mean screensaver/display turned off (that should have no effect?) or suspend. Unless you're developing an interactive application like a video player, I'd consider it bad style if your application messes with my energy settings.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld if the applications task is to perform a time consuming calculation, then its a viable reason to keep the mac from suspend or at least to have an option to prevent this.

Comment: @Yellow you are probably stuck with the native api or at least i do not remember having seen a Qt implementation for that.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: I mean the suspend state. Basically, I'm happy with the screen going to screensaver or on blank of course, but I don't want it to go into sleeping/suspend mode, as this would interrupt my calculations. I think that, given the fact that all this application is about is (reasonably) heavy computations that may run overnight, it's fair to expect it to 'mess' with the energy settings.

Comment: Yellow: if I want my computer to not suspend to finish your calculations faster, I change my energy settings. Otherwise, your calculations are simply continued when I resume. I don't see why your program should interfere with what should be under the sovereignty of the system/the user.

Comment: Disagree it's a duplicate; whether/how the multi-platform Qt framework supports it via Qt APIs would be valuable information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a thorough search through the Qt 5.2 API, it seems that Qt doesn't offer any functionality to change the energy settings (so neither for Mac, nor any other operating system). I haven't found any indication that it's on their road map either.

A possible solution for Mac OSX using Apple's Objective-C API can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596319/how-to-programmatically-prevent-a-mac-from-going-to-sleep/5596946#5596946) (thanks, @Kuba).

On Windows, power settings can be dealt with using the SetThreadExecutionState function (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302185/how-to-prevent-windows-from-entering-idle-state), C#).

Comment: Except `SetThreadExecutionState` does not prevent the display from turning off.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe actually it can also do that; use the flag `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED` if you don't want the display to turn off

Comment: @HyperQuantum: interesting point, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There are two aspects of this:

1. **Forced Sleep** If the user intends the system to sleep, and you prevent it, your users may well curse you. Forced sleep is also part of energy and thermal management, and is vital to prevent data loss and avoid destruction of hardware and mitigate possible fire risk.

   When I close the lid of my laptop, it better go to sleep and if I find an app that tries to circumvent it, it better be free or else I'm calling my credit card company for a chargeback. It's that simple, and I hope it's easy to understand why it would be so.
2. **Idle Sleep** What you want to do is not to *prevent* the system from going to sleep at all, but to only disable the idle sleep.

Disabling of idle sleep is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596946/1329652).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This sort of made sense in my head but I didn't know the right terms for it. 
Though the answer you link to is useful for native Mac programming, it is an Objective-C solution rather than a Qt/C++ solution.

Comment: @Yellow There is no Qt/C++ solution. You can freely use Objective-C/C++ from a Qt project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the Objective-C API, there's a C-based API underlying it. You can call `IOPMAssertionCreateWithDescription()` with an assertion type of `kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleSystemSleep`. That gives you an assertion ID reference. You cancel the assertion using `IOPMAssertionRelease()` to match the create call and any `IOPMAssertionRetain()` calls you may have made.

```
CFURLRef bundleURL = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle());
CFStringRef bundlePath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(bundleURL, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
CFRelease(bundleURL);

IOPMAssertionID assertion;
IOReturn result = IOPMAssertionCreateWithDescription(kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleSystemSleep,
    CFSTR("A name which makes sense for your app"),
    CFSTR("Some details"), CFSTR("A human-readable reason"),
    bundlePath, 0, NULL, &assertion);
CFRelease(bundlePath);
if (result != kIOReturnSuccess)
    /* handle error */;

// ... do computation ...

IOPMAssertionRelease(assertion);
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a command line utility "caffeinate" that prevents system from going to sleep. Here is an example of using this utility within QT framework:

https://github.com/githublucas420/KDE/blob/4436536a6a2beb1631f89968dfab566963dae073/plugins/screensaver-inhibit/screensaverinhibitplugin-macos.cpp