# Is SetThreadExecutionState portable?

Tags: c#, sleep, portability

The target framework of my application is `.NET 6.0`, and it will run on Windows, macOS, and Linux. I would like my application to prevent its host from entering sleep/idle mode while the application is performing certain tasks. I can achieve this **on Windows** by following steps such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6302309/947889).

However, I am not sure how portable these steps are. [MSDN page on `SetThreadExecutionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate?redirectedfrom=MSDN#requirements)   reads:

> Target Platform   Windows

Does it mean the above-linked approach is not portable? if not, is there any *universal* approach for preventing the host system from entering the sleep/idle state?

Comment: Are you sure you want this method, instead of [GC.TryStartNoGCRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion)?

Comment: I am not sure how disallowing garbage collection would prevent system sleep/idle.

Comment: No, it is not portable.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437735/prevent-system-from-going-to-sleep-suspend-how-xviewer-vlc-do-it

Comment: And I assume there is no portable alternative!?